# Unable to assign a Value in Unix after reading it from file

Tags: unix, sed

I am using Cygwin and intended to use the same script in Unix. I have a file `done.txt` which contains the value as `34523`. I want to replace every `?` occurence in the `CreateView.sql` file with `34523` and write a output to `CreateViewFinal.sql` file. But it is not doing intended job, instead it is directly assigning `$value` in the `CreateViewFinal.sql` file. Any help in this matter would be greatly. Find the script:

Script:

```
sed '14 ! d' result.txt >> done.txt
value=$(<done.txt)
echo "$value"
sed 's/?/$value/' CreateView.sql >> CreateViewFinal.sql
```

After doing all i am getting `CreateViewFinal.sql` as

```
create view Latest_Cust_Records_Final  as
select cust.* from MCT cust,goldencopy g,principalkey p
where g.catalogid=$value and cust.cproductkeyid=g.productkey  and cust.cmodversion=g.version 
and p.catalogid=$value and p.active='Y' and cust.cproductkeyid=p.productkeyid;
```

so i want that `$value` should get from `done.txt` and assign into the `CreateViewFinal.txt`. The desire result should look like

```
create view Latest_Cust_Records_Final  as
select cust.* from MCT cust,goldencopy g,principalkey p
where g.catalogid=34523 and cust.cproductkeyid=g.productkey  and cust.cmodversion=g.version 
and p.catalogid=34523 and p.active='Y' and cust.cproductkeyid=p.productkeyid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes in the sed invocation:

```
sed "s/?/$value/" CreateView.sql >> CreateViewFinal.sql
```

When using single quotes, shell variable references such as `$value` will not be substituted.

Comment: Hi thanks for valuable suggestion ...but it's saying now  "Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

where g.catalogid= and cust.cproductkeyid=g.productkey  and cust.cmodversion=g.version
                   *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00936: missing expression
"

Comment: basically it is returning nothing now

Comment: hey it worked after making chnages as sed "s/?/($value)/" CreateView.sql >> CreateViewFinal.sql